# Openlayers with Google Maps layer problem in IE: pan, zoom bars hidden

Tags: internet-explorer, google-maps, openlayers

Our rails app uses Openlayers js and we use a google map layer.  The code is like this:

```
function initMap() {
  var googleLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Map", {numZoomLevels: 18});
  var map = new OpenLayers.Map($('map'), { projection: "EPSG:4326", numZoomLevels: maxZoom });

  map.addLayer(googleLayer);

  map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
}
```

This works fine in Firefox, Chrome properly.  But in Internet Explorer (IE) 8, it doesn't show the layerswitcher.  Or rather, when the map is loading, the layerswitcher icon (+ symbol) can be seen.  But once the map is fully loaded, the icon disappears.  The same thing happens for panzoombar as well.

Can someone tell me why this could be happening?

Thanks,
Sridhar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of OpenLayers are you using? If you're not on 2.10, try upgrading. I had a compatibility issue like yours when using Google Maps v3 with OpenLayers. Version 2.10 fixed it.

Comment: I am using 2.7.  I will try 2.10 and see whether this problem disappears.